# documentation-builder license information

Tags: commercial

I saw tool from ubuntu web platform called documentation-builder https://docs.ubuntu.com/documentation-builder/en/ and this is what exactly I need for my product. And my product is commercial one. Can I use the HTML created by this tool for commercial purpose?

Comment: I thought this is place to discuss license and open source project. By default all license related questions are down voted. Redirect users to correct stackexchange platform before down voting or redirect users to https://quora.com :D that's so funny

Comment: This question does not seem useful because you did not seem to provide any research into the tool. As it is, your question is basically just asking us to visit that page and do the research for you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a cursory look at the project, my answer would be that you can not use document-builder to build your documentation. Not for a commercial application nor for an open-source one.

This conclusion is based on the fact that I can't find any license information about the project and that the project copies a (non-trivial) template from its sources into the output.

The fact that non-trivial parts of the document-builder project are copied means that the output from the program will be considered to be a "derived work."

The fact that no license information is available means that the project defaults to the "all rights reserved" copyright status, which means that you are not allowed to create derived works.

These two facts combined make that documentation-builder is effectively unusable.